# CSS div 100% layout

Tags: css, html

What is the most elegant way to achieve something like [that](http://www.infodim.eu/layout.png) with divs for IE7 and above and the other browsers(chrome,firefox,...)?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My personal favorite is the jQuery [`UI.Layout`](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/index.cfm) plugin. It mimics the very flexible Java 'border layout'. Though there are pure css methods, I find they take a lot of tweaking, and have side effects on other layout elements. Whereas with the javascript plugin I was able to get it working in minutes.

[Example](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos/example.html)

Comment: Looks very nice however i must hit "allow blocked content" in IE for the script to run and this is a disadvantage.I've been using jquery and IE does not complain.But with "jquery.layout" has a problem i think

Comment: It might depend on where the script is hosted.

Answer (score 2):

Take a [look at this](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/item/css-liquid-layout-21-fixed-fluid/), look at the source, it will show you what's involved in a fixed / fluid layout.

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/item/css-liquid-layout-21-fixed-fluid/

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for a [sticky footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/). Similar to faux columns, it looks like your desired result, but "cheats" in some sense. Other than that and tables, you won't be able to achieve that with CSS due to how height works (it can't inherit relative values, i.e. elements can't be set to 100% height if the parent has its height set to auto or a percentage value).